# Styling Single Page Wordpress Child Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, styling

Hi I have a child theme and I would like specific styling of my homepage only so for my `style.css` file. Would I need to include `body.home` before each element?

Example:

```
body.home .plus_own {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body.home .header_pad_n ul li:hover .round_inner{ 
  background: #7a56af;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. What results do you get when you try it with and without? The community here would normally expect you to have a go yourself first. Thanks.

Comment: The short-answer is yes, that's a fine way to do it, under the condition that your homepage has the `.home` class on the body-tag.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways you can apply style only to the home page, the one you mentioned is also an option. You can include the css using 'is_front_page' condition and hook it to the wp_head e.g.

```
 function front_page_css() {
    ?>
          <?php if(is_front_page() ) : ?>
        <style>
           .plus_own {
             position: absolute;
             top: 50%;
             left: 50%;
             transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
             color: red;
             font-weight: bold;
           }

           .header_pad_n ul li:hover .round_inner{ 
                 background: #7a56af;
               -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                transform: rotate(360deg);
             }
        </style>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'front_page_css');
```

There are list of conditions you can use see the link https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: It's not generally a good idea to add inline styles to a page. Adding the styles via a css-selector would be much more maintainable.

Comment: I disagree, it depends on what you are doing if you know that it's only going to use in that specific page there is no reason not to use it, if the option is there it's meant to be used. And i was just letting him know about the option available. There is absolutely no reason to down vote the answer.

Comment: There are many reasons not to use it. The main one being overriding externally linked styles with inline ones. I agree that there is a place to use this technique but some questions don't merit full answers. You've offered a good solution by suggesting `is_front_page` but I can't approve of the code example. Adding inline styles from php isn't a great idea because it creates confusion. It's kludgy, I don't mean any personal offense

Comment: cool, no offence.. i am politely disagree, I am aware about all the drawbacks and benefits, i just cant vouch that my answer deserves the downvote.